# How to make use of list of registered users on mysql database to create chat app

Tags: android, mysql

Good day, everyone. Please, I really need an answer to this.

I  am new to Android development. I am trying to develop an app meant for broadcast messaging. I have been able to create a database where registered users are stored in a table. However, I lack the idea of what to do next.

Most of the tutorials I have seen teach how to make use of users registered on the PARSE platform. But I wonder if I could be able to lift the users on MySQL database and integrate it with any chat client. Thanks.

Comment: Please y'all, kindly reply

Comment: Hi, if I'm right, you want to know how get your table's data into your app code ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Volley library, it's a library made by Google to make requests.
[here you have some explications about Volley](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800). You'll need to import volley library in your project.

you have to create the singleton class given by Google ([Here called mySingleton](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/volley/requestqueue.html)) and to create a request class with code like this one :

```
public class MyRequest {

    private Context context;
    private RequestQueue queue;

    public MyRequest(Context context, RequestQueue queue) {
        this.context = context;
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void getArticles(final GetArticlesCallback callback){
        String url = "YourScriptUrl";

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                   callback.onSuccess("I will get this string in the activity");    

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                   callback.onError("erreur : " + error.toString());

        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("tag", "postArgument1");
                map.put("tag2", "postArgument2");

                return map;
            }
        };

        queue.add(request);
    }

    public interface GetArticlesCallback{
        void onSuccess(String success);
        void onError(String error);
    }


}
```

And you call this class in your activity :

```
    //queue is a RequestQueue
    //request is a Myrequest 

    queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
    request = new MyRequest(this, queue);

 request.getArticles(new MyRequest.GetArticlesCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String success) {  

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String error, String id) {


            }
        });
```